Lower bound in law of large numbers without i.i.d. assumption
Consider a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ taking values in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$, not necessarily independent nor identically distributed. For every $n=1,2,\ldots$, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}= 1 | X_1, \ldots, X_n) \geq 1/2$.
Is there a classical result in probability theory I can use to say that almost surely, $\liminf_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n \geq 1/2$?

You can simply couple to a sequence $(Y_n)$ of independent Bernoulli$(1/2)$ random variables. The condition you have means that we can do this so that $X_n\geq Y_n$ for each $n$, and then law of large numbers for the $Y_n$ gives you what you want.
[edit] To be precise, for each possible choice of $y_1\leq x_1,\ldots,y_n\leq x_n$, set $$P(Y_{n+1}=1\mid X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}, X_n=x_n,\ldots,X_1=x_1, Y_n=y_n,\ldots,Y_1=y_1)=\\
\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2P(X_{n+1}=1\mid X_n=x_n,\ldots,X_1=x_1)}&\text{ if }X_{n+1}=1\\0&\text{ if }X_{n+1}=0.\end{cases}$$
The condition you have says this is always well-defined, and this ensures the $Y_n$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(1/2)$ with $Y_n\leq X_n$.

What do you mean by "couple" here? Can you add some details?

Thanks for pointing me towards coupling, it seems to be a method I was previously unaware of. However, I can't see how one can ensure that $X_n \geq Y_n$ while retaining the independence of the sequence $(Y_n)$.

@Aleksi I've edited to include details. This construction ensures that if you only condition on the previous values for both sequences, you get probability $1/2$, but if you also condition on $X_{n+1}$ you get a different value, so $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of everything previous but not of $X_{n+1}$.

@Aleksi in your example you are missing some factors. We have $P(Y_3=1\mid X_2=1)=\sum_{i,j}P(X_1=i,X_3=j\mid X_2=1)P(Y_3=1\mid X_1=i,X_2=1,X_3=j)$. Now the terms with $j=0$ vanish, and you get left with $\sum_i\frac{P(X_1=i,X_3=1\mid X_2=1)}{2P(X_3=1\mid X_2=1,X_1=i)}$.
